# How do I flatten groups of adjacent same nodes?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Suppose I have the following sequence of elements:

```
<outer>
  <e>…</e>  <!-- Adjacent <e> should be grouped if they aren’t yet. -->
  <e>…</e>
  <group>
    <e>…</e>
    <e>…</e>
  </group>
  <e>…</e>
  <e>…</e>
</outer>
```

And I’d like to consolidate those elements `<e>` that have not yet been grouped, i.e. the output would be

```
<outer>
  <group-foo>  <!-- Grouped elements. -->
    <e>…</e>
    <e>…</e>
  </group-foo>
  <group-bar>
    <e>…</e>
    <e>…</e>
  </group-bar>
  <group-foo>
    <e>…</e>
    <e>…</e>
  </group-foo>
</outer>
```

I just can’t quite figure out how to select a *group* of adjacent elements (a node set); closest idea was to select `//e[name(parent::*) = 'outer']` or some such but that assumes a certain parent element and it returns a single node set, whereas I’d need two.

Comment: Please ask your other question separately. I don't think it's the same problem.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724633/how-do-i-flatten-text-nodes-and-nested-nodes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use a so-called *sibling recursion*:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/outer">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="e[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::e])] | group"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e">
    <group-foo>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <!-- immediate sibling in the same group -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::e]" mode="collect" />
    </group-foo>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e" mode="collect">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <!-- immediate sibling in the same group -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::e]" mode="collect" />
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="group">
    <group-bar>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </group-bar>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**No recursion. Using keys** (**[Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kE-ByPrecedingNonE" match="e[not(name(..) = 'group')]"
   use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::e)][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e[not(name(..) = 'group')]"/>

  <xsl:template match=
   "e[generate-id()
    = generate-id(key('kE-ByPrecedingNonE',
                      generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::e)][1])
                      )[1]
                  )]">
      <group-generated>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=
        "key('kE-ByPrecedingNonE',
             generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::e)][1])
             )" mode="inGroup"/>
      </group-generated>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="inGroup">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided source-xml document**:

```
<outer>
  <e>…</e>
  <e>…</e>
  <group>
    <e>…</e>
    <e>…</e>
  </group>
  <e>…</e>
  <e>…</e>
</outer>
```

**the wanted correct result is produced**:

```
<outer>
   <group-generated>
      <e>…</e>
      <e>…</e>
   </group-generated>
   <group>
      <e>…</e>
      <e>…</e>
   </group>
   <group-generated>
      <e>…</e>
      <e>…</e>
   </group-generated>
</outer>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule (template) copies to the output every node as is. We also give it a name so that we can not only use it when applying templates, but also call it directly -- as we do in step 4. below.
2. A template matching any `<e>` element that is not already inside a `<group>`. This has no body -- we want to only handle such elements in our next templates -- not when the identity template selects it for execution.
3. A template that matches any `<e>` element that is the first in a "non-covered" group. This uses the idea behind the Muenchian grouping method -- if you are unfamiliar with it, learn it well -- you won't be sorry. This template generates a wrapper element (called "group-generated") for the whole group and inside this wrapper applies templates to all `<e>`s in the group in mode "inGroup" -- where these are simply copied.
4. The template in mode "inGroup" simply delegates to the identity rule to copy the selected node. Thus any matched node is copied as-is. Here, if we decide, we can perform any other required "inGroup" processing.