# How do I flatten text nodes and nested nodes?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I’m trying to flatten an element’s text nodes and nested inlined elements

```
<e>something <inline>rather</inline> else</e>
```

into

```
<text>something </text>
<text-inline>rather</text-inline>
<text> else</text>
```

Using `e/text()` would return both text nodes but how do I flatten all nodes in order for arbitrarily inlined elements (even nested)?

Comment: It seems that you want just: `e//text()` -- this evaluates to the sequence of all text nodes descendents (even indirect/nested) of the element `e`. If my guess is off, then please, edit the question and provide a  more clear and precise/complete definition of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure "flatten" is the right term for this. It seems all you want to do is change some text nodes into elements containing the same text. This can be done by a template matching these text nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="e/text()">
    <text>
        <xsl:copy/>
    </text>
</xsl:template>
```

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7n4

---

Of course, if you also want to rename `inline` to `text-inline`, you will need another template for that:

```
<xsl:template match="inline">
    <text-inline>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </text-inline>
</xsl:template>
```